# Final object in fields of characteristic $ 0 $?

Tags: field-theory, category-theory

In his answer to this question: [Category of Field has no initial object](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81458/category-of-field-has-no-initial-object), Arturo Madigin indicated that the field of rational numbers is the initial object in the category of fields of characteristic $ 0 $.

(There is also an interesting discussion trying to characterize such fields here: [Examples of fields of characteristic $ 0 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4241/examples-of-fields-of-characteristic-0).)

Does the category of fields of characteristic $ 0 $ have a final object? Somehow it would be great if it were the real numbers, but because of my limited background, I can’t imagine showing either hom existence or uniqueness.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't imagine why it would be the reals. There's always $\Bbb C$, for example.

Comment: Yeah but just because $\Bbb C$ contains $\Bbb R$ shouldn't matter. For example, the final object in sets is the singleton, not two, an infinite set or anything else. What's your rationale?

Comment: No field containing an element squaring to $-1$ admits a morphism to $\mathbb{R}$ (such as $\mathbb{C}$). Neither does any field bigger than $\mathbb{R}$ (such as $\mathbb{R}$ adjoin $|2^{\mathbb{R}}|$ new variables).

Comment: Qiaochu (in his answer) has hit upon a fundamental difference between morphisms of fields and those of sets (which I ought to have mentioned, honestly), which should tell you why it matters that $\Bbb C$ contains $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Any morphism between fields is injective, and there are fields of characteristic $0$ of arbitrarily large cardinality.

Comment: Can you explain why you mentioned arbitrary large cardinality? Afaik, sets have a final object even if there are sets of arbitrarily large cardinality. Also, any good references as to why morphisms are required to be injective?

Comment: @alancalvitti: Any morphism of fields is injective for the following reason: any morphism of unital rings $f:R\to S$ is required to take $1_R$ to $1_S$. Now consider what the kernel can be if $R$ is a field.

Comment: @alancalvitti: As to your first question: can any given field $F$ be a final object if there are fields $L$ of larger cardinality than $F$ and any field morphism must be injective?

Comment: @alan: if the cardinality remark were the only important step then I wouldn't have mentioned the fact that morphisms of fields are injective. Both ingredients are necessary. If $F$ is a field and $L$ a field larger than $F$, then there aren't any morphisms $L \to F$ (because morphisms of fields are injective, because fields have no nontrivial ideals, because nontrivial elements of nontrivial ideals are not invertible). Hence $F$ cannot be the terminal object.

Comment: @alancalvitti: For comparison, the category of sets and injections doesn't have a finial object either.

Comment: @alan: The point is that sets don't stop at the cardinality of the continuum. Since the morphisms are injective functions the cardinality does not decrease. In fact, says Qiaochu, we can find objects of any infinite cardinality there. So a terminal object would have to have cardinality which is larger than any other; which is a contradiction to the fact that there is no largest cardinal.

Comment: Thanks, it would be nice to have a database where one can look up  the properties of various categories. What's an example of a char 0 field of cardinality greater than that of the continuum?

Comment: @alan, Qiaochu already answered this for you in the third comment to the question: just adjoin as many indeterminates as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Given a category where all maps are monomorphisms, suppose that there are two different parallel maps $f,g: A\to B$. Then any given map $h: B\to T$ will produce two different maps $h\circ f, h\circ g: A\to T$. In particular, there cannot be a final object. Also, there cannot be any product $A\leftarrow P \rightarrow B$ because the two maps $(id_A,f),(id_A,g): A \to P$ would need to be equal and different at the same time (*).

For fields of characteristic $0$, take $A=B=\mathbb{C}$ (the complex numbers), the identity map for $f$, and conjugation for $g$.

Actually, that category has pullbacks. So, if you already know that it does not have products, you also know that it does not have a terminal object.

(*) I have seen this argument in some exercise, but I do not remember where.